# Protovis force re-render

Tags: websocket, protovis

I know Protovis isn't really meant to be used this way, but is there a workaround for destroying what's currently in a `pv.Panel` and re-`add()`'ing and re-`render()`'ing a panel?

I'm working on a visualization which was built to be static and trying to migrate it to being updated periodically via WebSockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can have Protovis re-render without destroying the panel.  You can update the data used by a panel, and call render on it again.  For example:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3];

var panel = new pv.Panel()
    .data(data)
    .add(pv.Bar)
    ...

panel.render();  // initial render

data = [4, 5, 6];  
panel.data(data);  // update the data
panel.render();    // re-render
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up working around by making all children of the panel invisible and re-adding new children, because in fact while the above solution works, it doesn't extend to things like changing scales based on data bounds. If you're graphing data from 1-10 and the next version of your data goes from 1-50, you can't rescale your graph by updating the data, can you?

Comment: Nicolas, You are correct, when you adjust your data, you need to rebuild your scale objects if you want to change their domain or range based on the data.